# What organization is responsible for the maintenance of Eclipse for PHP (PDT)?

Tags: php, eclipse, eclipse-pdt

all.
  does somebody know what's the Maintenance organization of the following files which is from eclipse's plugins.

```
libxml.php      mysql.php       pdo_pgsql.php   standard.php    xmlwriter.php   
SimpleXML.php   ctype.php       ftp.php         imagick.php     mbstring.php    mysqli.php      pdo_sqlite.php  tidy.php        xsl.php         
basic.php       curl.php        gd.php          imap.php        mcrypt.php      odbc.php        pgsql.php       tokenizer.php   zip.php
```

those files at eclispe_workspace/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.php.core

the plugin name should be PDT .

I wonder whether the maintenance organization is PDT or PHP ?

I scanned on PDT sites http://www.eclipse.org/projects/project_summary.php?projectid=tools.pdt  and PHP sites  http://php.net

I didn't find those file.

===========update=================

hi,thanks for your reply,I update the post,append the reason I want to know.

because I am developing an extention  for emacs, I wonder whether I can use those file and update it as soon as possible.

Comment: Given the lead people on the eclipse page are Zend employees, probably PHP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The right answer is available at http://www.eclipse.org/projects/project.php?id=tools.pdt. The project is active as can be seen by the commit activity! It is only the download package which is not supported, which is slightly different from the PDT project.

In the last 3 months most of the code has been contributed by Zend technologies (as seen on the above mentioned page), and I think IBM also contributes to it but not sure.

Comment: In the last 2 months, Zend has contributed one big commit, and one single user has been doing the other commits. The project isn't that active: http://dash.eclipse.org/dash/commits/web-app/summary.cgi?company=y&month=x&project=tools.pdt

Comment: The project is not inactive. In any case a release happens in June end for most Eclipse projects and commit activity goes down a bit around this time.